# NestJS. Не работает глобальная валидация данных, если dto указан как union type, какая есть альтернатива?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, nestjs

Есть обработчик запроса в контроллере, который отвечает за создание пользователей.
Пользователи бывают двух видов с ролью Тренер и с ролью Клиент.
В зависимости от роли пользователя могу приходить 2 вида данных.
Соответственно я создал 2 dto класса - `CreateClientDto`, `CreateTrainerDto`.
В обработчике я указал для dto типизацию, как объединение двух этих классов - `CreateClientDto | CreateTrainerDto`:

```
@Post('register')
  public async create(@Body() dto: CreateClientDto | CreateTrainerDto) {
    const newUser = await this.authService.register(dto);

    if (newUser.role === UserRole.Client) {
      return fillDTO(ClientRdo, newUser);
    }

    return fillDTO(TrainerRdo, newUser);
}
```

Но при таком раскладе валидация данных перестаёт работать.
Если избавиться от union типа и указывать отдельно, или `CreateClientDto`, или `CreateTrainerDto`, то тогда всё ОК. Но такой вариант мне не подходит.
Я думал о том чтобы объединить эти 2 класса в 1 универсальный класс `CreateUserDto`, но в этом случае у пользователя появляется возможность вне зависимости от выбранной роли комбинировать и записывать в БД свойства не характерные для своей роли.

Как можно решить данную проблему?
Может можно как-то описать класс CreateUserDto, но так чтобы если у него роль Клиент, то он не мог себе присвоить свойства присущие Тренеру? И тоже самое для пользователя с ролью Тренер.

Comment: Возможно я чего-то не понял, а что мешает [так](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgThAhsCMA2BLCA7YARYAeygF4oBvAKCijkLQgC4oByQLhBBuEEA4QQVhBBeEEBCIC0oBfSpVCQa8JCgAqcRBmwQ4BYmSo06DZiwGABEH48DwmgGdEaRHBDNsAVwC2AI1WjxlAMaFs54FBOzDLIqJg4+ERQAD6wCKEKSipqUZrUtPRMrJy8giwANOmW1rbMAEwADFUelEA) сделать ?

Comment: @DaniilLoban не это немного не то что нужно. Кроме того у вас в демонстрации TypeScript ошибку кидает :)

Comment: `то он не мог себе присвоить свойства присущие Тренеру` так он и должен кидать ошибку потому что у клиента нет запрпраты только у тренера)),  ну видимо тогда я не понял что нужно, дополните вопрос подробностями, может кто-то ответит

Answer (score 1):

Это решается либо с помощью интерфейсов, либо с помощью использования библиотеки CASL.

Рекомендую использовать, так как в будущих проектах и при потенциальном росте сервиса с большой долей вероятности понадобятся кастомные роли.

[Документация](https://casl.js.org/v6/en/)

[Статья на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/334076/)

Comment: Спасибо за совет, сейчас почитаю.